# Can the set of endomorphisms of $(\mathbb R,+)$ have cardinality strictly between $\frak c$ and $\frak{c^c}$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let $\frak c$ be the cardinality of the reals. I know that in ZF the set of endomorphisms of $(\mathbb R,+)$ can have at least two different cardinalites:

- If we allow the axiom of choice, you can consider the reals as a vector space over the rationals, and get $\frak{c^c}$ homomorphisms. Note that with the axiom of choice this is the same as $\frak c!$(cardinality of set of bijections) and $2^\frak c$.
- On the other hand there is [the Solovay model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay_model) which is a model where every set of reals is Baire measurable. By theorem of Pettis all Baire measurable homomorphisms between Polish groups are continuous. There are $\frak c$ continuous homomorphisms $(\mathbb R,+)$ to itself.
- Asaf Karagila brought up, in a version of this [question on math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3367572/can-the-set-of-endomorphisms-of-mathbbr-have-cardinality-strictly-betwe#comment6930439_3367572), that it is consistent that $\aleph_1 \times \frak c$ can not support a group structure.  This means the set of endomorphisms can not have that cardinality(in such models).

**Questions:** Can the cardinality of the set of endomorphisms,$\frak e$, be strictly between $\frak c$ and $\frak{c^c}$? Somewhat vague—is there a sort of classification of what cardinals $\frak e$ could be(for example you need to be able to put a group structure on it, are there any other restrictions)? I am also interested in the same questions except looking at isomorphisms and the cardinals are $\frak c$ and $\frak {c} !$.

(this is an edited version of a question I [asked on math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3367572/29123), I figured most of the active math.se set theory people already saw it there and I probably should have asked it here anyways)

Comment: Martin Sleziak pointed out, correctly, on MSE that choice is unnecessary for the cardinal arithmetic at the end of the first bullet point.

Comment: I hate to interject with an uninformed comment, but what does cardinality mean without choice? Are we talking about sets modulo existence of a bijection? Or something about maps to or from cardinals?

Comment: @TimCampion Tim, yes, I assume we are talking about the large poset that is the posetal collapse of the preorder defined by $X \leq Y$ iff there exists an injection from $X$ to $Y$ (by Cantor-Schroeder-Bernstein, $X \leq Y$ and $Y \leq X$ iff $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic). The question is certainly sensible under this assumption.

Comment: @Tim: Cardinals, without choice, refer to (and should refer to) the general notion of cardinality. But since ordinals are just so damn useful, cardinals are defined as initial ordinals for well-ordered sets, and Scott equivalence classes otherwise (i.e., take the class-sized equivalence class modulo bijections, and cut it on the least rank it's not empty).

Comment: @Todd: Actually it's the only sensible way to read this question, since if you talk about cardinals as well-ordered sets only, then either $\Bbb R$ can be well-ordered, in which case we fallback to the AC situation, or it's not a cardinal to begin with, in which case the question is meaningless. Since the question is not quite meaningless, reading it as "cardinals are initial ordinals" makes no sense. :-)

Comment: @AsafKaragila In fact it didn't occur to me to read it any other way.

Comment: @AsafKaragila You just doubled my confusion by giving two incompatible definitions of “cardinal” in the same comment! :) Since only the first one applies to the continuum I suppose I have my answer for the purposes of this question, but my confusion over the choiceless meaning of “cardinal” will just have to persist I suppose...

Comment: @Tim: It's unfortunate that some books define it in one way, and other books in the other way. Since the majority of books focus on ZFC, rather than ZF, then you'd think it doesn't really matter. But then things like this happen.